# Box-shadow of Toolbar is overlapping on sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I need to remove shadow at the top left corner which is overlapped on the sidebar, need a perfect border.

```
 sidebarContainer: {
    boxShadow: "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)",
    "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)",
    "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)",
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: 82,
  }


  topNavigationContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: "17px 27px",
    position: "fixed",
    height: 82,
    zIndex: 1,
    boxShadow: "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)",
    "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)",
    "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)"   }
```

using material Ui useStyles for styling

Comment: can u provide us sendbox example?

Comment: Please go through this, I think it'll help - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-box-shadow-to-the-clip-path-object/

Comment: your sidebar `z-index` should be bigger than header `z-index`